# How do I parameterize a war deployment on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jetty

I have a war file that is being deployed to Tomcat.  Whenever the file is re-deployed or the app is restarted, it should require the admin to specify a root password.

To satisfy this requirement, something like a command line prompt on restart or specifying some sort of parameters to a tomcat command would be sufficient.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?  Extra points if you can also describe how to do the same for jetty.

Comment: This seems like a server setup / configuration question, not a programming question.

Comment: To a programmer, everything is a programming question. :-)  But fair enough, maybe more appropriate for Server Fault.